Disney film with animation and live action, Mickey disappearing
I remember this from when I was about 5 years old, which would mean it happened in 1990-91, so I'm not sure I remember it correctly. The film could have been much older than that.
I'm quite certain it was a video tape I (or, well, my parents) had rented. I used to think it was Fantasia but others who have watched Fantasia don't remember this part.
What I remember is that something had happened to Mickey, which may have been the part where he's a wizard's apprentice and makes the brooms dance. But right after that it switched to a live action part that looked like a couple of newscasters, like on the news you can watch on TV, saying that Mickey had disappeared and no one knew where he was.
That frightened me and I stopped the tape, and I never watched it again.
What did I actually watch? As I mentioned earlier, I used to think it was Fantasia but (although I've still not watched it) other people don't remember anything about a newscast.

I believe you saw the 1988 TV Special Mickey's 60th Birthday.

This film combines live action/original animation and library animation. Mickey steals a magic hat from [the Fantasia] Sorcerer and is put under a spell by the angry magi so that no one will recognize him until he finds his own magic within. While Mickey is on his quest, network news teams around the country desperately try to find the famous, beloved mouse who has mysteriously disappeared. 

You can see a relevant bit (Mickey's disappearance being reported) here around 2:20:



